# Reading until just the end of line.

Tags: c++, file-io

So I'm trying to read in from a file that has an unknown/arbitrary number of characters on a line and unknown/arbitrary number of lines.

I'm trying to make a dynamic 2D array to move all the information into the file to so I can make A Game of Life but I need to first read the file in to get the number of columns and rows.

I already understand how to get the number of rows. I'm just going to read in the file using getline and place a counter on how many times it repeats until EOF.

I'm stuck though on how to get the number of columns. Is there a way for the get function to only read until the end of line?

Comment: How the columns are separated in the line? That is how to count the columns?

Comment: Please don't use the standard EOF method.
More information here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/145699-eof-and-reading-text-files-c/

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'd say a concrete code sample would be fairly appropriate here. There are too much open points left from the question, that may have influence on the actually experienced behavior. If there's not insufficient information to diagnose the problem, the question is too broad at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've done getline you can call `.length()` on the string to get how many characters it is. For example:

```
getline (cin,line);
columns = line.length();
```

The number of characters you get back should represent the number of columns.

Comment: +1 for reasonable answer, although I would have used `length` since that's more idiomatic for srings.

Comment: @Alf sounds good. I'll change it. I do like `length` better for strings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thats exactly what I needed. Time to get back to coding :).